# Tool to manage CITRIX application dependency libraries

Tags: hp, citrix, update

I need to use some tools to help me during the release and deployment management of package application. I would like to use HP release control and maybe HP quality centre.

But I do not understand, how I will be able to be sure that when I will upgrade to the new version of CITRIX, that all my application will not have any problems? Can you understand my case? Do you know any tools to manage the dependency libraries between applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a record-keeping tool to substitute for actual testing. You need to have a test environment, where you first have an equivalent configuration to your production server, then upgrade Citrix, and then test it.